# Importing CSV with HTML markup in some values using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file where some of the values contain decoded HTML markups (e.g. `&lt;b%gt;Example&lt;/b%gt;`) that I try to insert in a SharePoint list.

When I iterate through the values using PowerShell it splits up the strings at `,` no matter I do.
I have tried wrapping the strings with `"` and `'` but then PowerShell throws this error:

> update : Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid
>   text value.
>
> A text field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try
>   again."
>
> At C:\Scripts\Configuration\SystemConfiguration.ps1:41
>   char:22
>   +             $spListItem.update <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Here's an example on one of the values:

```
"&lt;b&gt;Dear {0} Team,&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;{1} request was completed &lt;a href='{2}'&gt;{3}&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;{2}&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;To download the PDF of the form please click  &lt;a href='{6}'&gt;Here&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;br/&gt;In case of questions, please contact {4}.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;With best regards&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;{5}"
```

Can anyone provide me with some tips on how to ensure the above value can be successfully inserted?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by fooling around with some `HttpUtility` methods.

```
$Value = &lt;b&gt;Dear {0} Team,&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;{1} request was completed &lt;a href='{2}'&gt;{3}&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;{2}&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;To download the PDF of the form please click  &lt;a href='{6}'&gt;Here&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;br/&gt;In case of questions, please contact {4}.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;With best regards&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;{5}
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($Value)
```